# python: getting a response from check_output before the command is finished

Tags: python, subprocess, youtube-dl

I am using python to run [Youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/), a software used to download videos from YouTube and other sites. I am using it specifically to download the audio from YouTube videos. I am able to download the audio from a YouTube video using python by using check_output() to execute the youtube-dl.exe file saved on my computer.

Below is the method I wrote to execute the youtube-dl file and download a song. It returns a huge string of text that is the output from the youtube-dl program.

```
from subprocess import check_output

#downloads the audio from a song to wherever the python script is
def getSong(songUrl):
    return check_output('C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe --max-quality FORMAT --extract-audio ' + songUrl, shell=True)
```

When I run this method in python, it will wait for the command to be completed, then return a huge response containing lots of information. This includes generic info outputted at the end of the download, but it also (if run through command prompt) will give out info about the download progress every few seconds. The problem is, when running it in python, I get all of this progress information after it is finished downloading.

Is there any way to get the output from the check_output() method while it is still running? that way I would be able to make a progress bar for the download.

**EDIT:**

update: below is the current code that I have gotten to work as I want to except for one small exception...

```
import subprocess
songUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO3lN-hugaQ"
process = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe", "--max quality", "FORMAT", "--extract-audio", songUrl], shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line,
process.communicate()
```

When I run this new above code, it will start to print out information line by line as it is generated in the executed command, but all of the information regarding percent downloaded is all printed out at the very end. When I tried running the same command in command prompt, I discovered that the text that gives information about percent downloaded is actually changed every second or so, rather than a new line being created with updated information, as I suspected was true based on the output in python. Do you think there is any way around this, so I can get the information necessary for a progress bar?

Comment: The short answer is: don't use `check_output()` then, as it explicitly waits for the process to exit first. It is a utility method using `Popen()`; don't use it if it doesn't fit your use case and instead use any of the other convenience methods or go straight to `Popen()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Popen instead. Then you can do something like the following:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe", "--max-quality", "FORMAT", "--extract-audio", "songUrl"], shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

while process.poll() is None:
    result = process.stdout.read()
    # do some calculations for percentage done
```

Also as a general rule of thumb, you should avoid using shell=True to prevent potential security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Crap you beat me to it. Change to `process.poll() is None` however to be more correct.

Comment: Done for sake of correctness, thanks. To be fair, there's probably also a better way to read the output as well. It all depends on what the process outputs and the type of calculations to do for a progress bar.

Comment: hello! I tried what you posted and the song did download but all the output was printed out at the very end. I tried exactly what you put up there, except I swapped out an actual song url and added "print result" directly below where the result variable was defined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @bs7280 You'd probably want to show us that code, easier to solve the issue because a print in the `while` loop should print the output. Also Bob, you can (not sure what the best practice is) skip the `[..]` brackets when using `Shell=True`, and input it as a single joined string instead, tends to bug out less for some reasons. Other than that, great work!

Comment: hello, I added the code I currently have and a description of what I am dealing with in my main post.

Comment: `result = process.stdout.read()` will read until EOF, so no improvement to the current situation. `result = process.stdout.read(<some appropriate block size>)` will do the trick, however.

Comment: @bs7280 Use the code **Bob** gave you, the `while process.poll() is None` + `print process.stdout.readline()` should do the trick, not sure why you're using `.communicate()` at all in the end, or why you're using `iter(...)` either tbh.

Comment: thanks everyone, I was using .communicate() and iter() because I found another implementation elsewhere because I was not able to get the original method in Bob's answer to work, but I have it all figured out now and I was able to get exactly what I wanted through both Bob's code and glglgl's help. Thanks all.